# Remove open button form uilocalnotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to remove the "open" app button from the alert notification. When user set the notification and notification appears when app is in background I want to remove the open button.[image]

Please see the image. This is the by default alert appears when notification fire. I want to remove that open button.

This is the Code when user schedule the notification

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationOnlyOneTime:(NSDate *)fireDate
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
    if(!category){
        localNotif.category = @"ACTIONABLECATEGORY";
    }
    else{

       localNotif.category = @"ACTIONABLE";

    }
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Time Up";
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


}
```

and this is the code in which I create my alert

```
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *accept=[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
            [snooze setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
            [snooze setTitle:@"Accept"];
            [snooze setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
            [snooze setDestructive:NO];
            [snooze setAuthenticationRequired:YES];

 UIMutableUserNotificationAction *maybe=[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
                [watch setTitle:@"Maybe"];
                [watch setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
                [watch setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
                [watch setDestructive:NO];
                [watch setAuthenticationRequired:YES];

           UIMutableUserNotificationAction *decline=[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];


                [watch setTitle:@"Decline"];
                [watch setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
                [watch setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
                [watch setDestructive:NO];
                [watch setAuthenticationRequired:YES];


            UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
            actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
            [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
            [actionCategory setActions:@[decline, accept,maybe]
                            forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: show code where you create alert

Comment: I edit my code @RomanSimenok

Comment: @salmancs43 in this code you aren't create alert, here you create actions, and not all as i see.